# Solution verification: Subspace of connected space is connected

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

In my general topology textbook they made the following question:

> Is it true that every subspace of a connected space is connected?

I answered affirmative and I came up with the following proof:

---

#### My proof

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and let $(Y,\tau_y)$ be a subspace of $(X,\tau)$.

Let's assume that $(X,\tau)$ is connected: this means that the only clopen subsets of $X$ are $X$ and $\emptyset$.

Let $A \neq X$ and $A \neq \emptyset$. Let $A \in \tau$, then $X\setminus A \notin \tau$.

Because $A \in \tau$ and $X\setminus A \notin \tau$, then we know that $A \cap Y \in \tau_y$ and $(X\setminus A)\cap Y \notin \tau_y$. We know that $(X\setminus A)\cap Y = Y\setminus A$.

We also know that $Y\setminus (A \cap Y) = Y\setminus A = (X\setminus A)\cap Y \notin \tau_y$.

So if $A \cap Y \in \tau_y$ then $Y\setminus (A \cap Y) \notin \tau_y$, which means that the set cannot be clopen, thus proving that the only clopen sets are $Y$ and $\emptyset$, and that $(Y,\tau_y)$ is also connected?

---

Is this proof correct? Because I searched online and some people claimed that the answer to the question is negative, yet I "proved" affirmative. What mistake did I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\cap Y$ can be in $\tau_y$ and $(X-A)\cap Y$ in $\tau_y$ also, consider $\{0,1\}\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $A=(-1/2,1/2)$

$A\cap \{0,1\}=\{0\}$ and $(X-A)\cap\{0,1\}=\{1\}=(1/2,3/2)\cap\{0,1\}$.

There can exists $A'\in \tau$ with $A'\cap Y=A\cap Y$.

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb R$ is connected; the subspace $\{0,1\}$ of $\Bbb R$ is not. Note that $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are clopen **in** $\bf\{0,1\}$, even though neither is open in $\Bbb R$. Your mistake is in thinking that if $S\subseteq X$ is not closed in $X$, then $S\cap Y$ cannot be closed in $Y$. In my example take $A=(\leftarrow,1)$; then $X\setminus A=[1,\to)$ is not open in $\Bbb R$, but its intersection with $\{0,1\}$ is $\{1\}$, which **is** open in $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Yes I know that my proof and my answer is wrong, I'm trying to locate the mistake now

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães: Your mistake is in thinking that if a set $S$ is not open in $X$, then $S\cap Y$ cannot be open in $Y$.

Comment: In line 6 you wrote $(X\setminus A) \cap Y$ instead of $X\setminus (A \cap Y)$